# Adding events to dynamically generated WPF elements

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-3.5

I have several Border elements with stuff inside that are generated at runtime. I managed to spawn them but now I want to associate events to them like MouseEnter, Click, etc., but I don't know how.
I managed to associate each Border element a unique name (Name property) so I could work with them if I ever needed. How can I add events to each one of the generated Border elements, in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <Style x:Key="BorderNameStyle" TargetType="{x:Type BorderName}">
                <EventSetter Event="MouseEnter" Handler="itm_MouseEnter"></EventSetter>
                <EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonUp" Handler="itm_MouseLeftButtonUp"></EventSetter>
                <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseRightButtonUp" Handler="itm_MouseRightButtonUp"></EventSetter>
                <EventSetter Event="MouseLeave"  Handler="itm_MouseLeave"></EventSetter>
                <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="ItemMouseDoubleClick"></EventSetter>
</Style>
```

By defining styles for the Border or code behind you need to call the routed events like below.

```
    border.MouseEnter += new MouseEventHandler(border_MouseEnter);

    void border_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
     {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(btn_Click);
     }
    void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use like this

```
 border.MouseEnter += new MouseEventHandler(border_MouseEnter);

void border_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
   throw new NotImplementedException();
 }
```